# Change call and name of gather environment

Tags: gather

I'm aware that it is not so doable, but just asking: using LaTeX a lot this years I noticed that I used many many times the `\begin{gather*} \end{gather*}` call, so much that I must have spent at least 10.000 seconds in writing just all the `\begin{gather*}\end{gather*}`commands: I want to ask if there is a way to rename the whole thing in order to make it faster, something like `\b{g*}\e{g*}`.

Comment: A good text editor with snippets and auto completion would probably be the better solution

Comment: As DG' (and many others) says: learn to use your editor is a much better solution. Writing envs in such a short form makes the code very hard to read

Comment: I can type `\begin{gather*}` in less than one second, maybe 1.5 if I'm lazy. Did you really type in more than 5000 `gather*` environments?

Comment: LaTeX's new hook-system turns copying environments into a non-trivial undertaking as the new hook-system ensures that with every environment there is something that depends on/is derived from the name of the current environment. (E.g., you'd want the hooks of the environment `gather*` to be the same as the hooks of the environment `g*`, but -afaik- the new hook-system would assume different sets of hooks...) However - overriding existing definitions, you can have macros `\b` and `\e` map their arguments to calls to `\begin{...}/\end{...}`. But this would not work out with all environments. ...

Comment: ... But this would not work out with all environments. E.g., this would not work out with environments like `gather`/`gather*` which do `\collect@body` which implies searching for a "verbatim-phrase" `\end{<name of environment>}` within subsequent tokens of the token-stream.

Comment: @DG' I don't know how this works, can you give an example? Thanks

Comment: @egreg Yes! I did a try and writing `\begin{gather*}...\end{gather*}` I use around 3.5/4 seconds and I have an average of 2 equations per page: considering all the lessons I transcribed on the spot plus all the material I've written myself the result is huge!

Comment: @UlrichDiez Sorry, I thank you for your explanation, but it's too technical for me, I just know the basics

Comment: @RobTan - [Here is one example using vim](https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/) . But you don't have to use vim, similar setups are possible for many editors

Comment: @DG' Great link thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

As other pointed out in comments, a far better idea is to use your editor's features to auto-type blocks of code after you type only 3 or 4 letters. For example, as soon as I type "fig2" in my editor, a 15-line block code appears to get two figures side-by-side.

Each editor has its own way to do it, here are two examples with common ones.

With TeXstudio, go to the Macros menu, Edit macros. You'll get a window where you'll be able to create "macros" (code snippets) with a name, a block of code and a trigger. The trigger is the short series of letters that will trigger the auto-typing of the block of code.

With VS Code, go to Preferences, User Snippets. A menu will make use you choose a language (latex.json), then a text file will be automatically opened and you'll be able to create any snippet with a trigger. The exact syntax is explained inside the file.

Also, VS Code (more precisly its LaTeX plugin) has a number of LaTeX-related snippets preprogrammed. For example, typing BEQ automatically generates an `equation` environment and prepositions the cursor inside.

If your editor doesn't offer that sort of feature... I'd use another one.

Fun fact: since VS Code can interface with my Stream Deck, I attached all my code snippets to keys on the deck. Very smooth to use. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So with TeXworks is not possible?

Comment: Those were only examples. However, I haven't used TeXworks in a very long time (its features are a bit too limited), so I don't know, sorry. But a quick look at its documentation (page 23) seems to indicate that it has some support for snippets.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll look

Comment: *> However, I haven't used TeXworks in a very long time (its features are a bit too limited)*   ...   Emacs Lisp rules. ;-)